# Why is PUT request not updating the Django rest framework database?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update the database using a PUT request. Currently, I am able to update the database from the Django Admin successfully but I want to do same using a PUT request.

When ever I make a PUT request, I get a 200 OK response with no errors but the data is not updating in the database. I dont know why. I am confused. Someone please help me. Thank you.

models.py

```
class User_Order(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    shirts = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    shorts = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    trousers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    total_units = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    
    shirts_amount = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    shorts_amount = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    trousers_amount = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    
    total = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    
    

    verified = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    doing_laundry = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    delivery_underway = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    delivered = models.BooleanField(null=True)

    address = models.TextField(default='')

    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = self.order.user
        self.id = self.order.id
        self.shirts = self.order.shirts
        self.shorts = self.order.shorts
        self.trousers = self.order.trousers
        self.total_units = self.order.total_units
        self.shirts_amount = self.order.shirts_amount
        self.shorts_amount = self.order.shorts_amount
        self.trousers_amount = self.order.trousers_amount
        self.total = self.order.total
        self.verified = self.order.verified
        self.doing_laundry = self.order.doing_laundry
        self.delivery_underway = self.order.delivery_underway
        self.delivered = self.order.delivered
        self.address = self.order.address

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.order.user.username} Order'
```

serializers.py

```
class UserUser_OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User_Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def UserOrdersUpdate(request, pk):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    user_order = User_Order.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'PUT':

        serializer = UserUser_OrderSerializer(instance=user_order, data=request.data, many = False, partial=True)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because in `User_Order.save()` method you replace all fields from  `User_Order` where all the data from serializer is stored with `Order` instance values.

Also you can use class based view [UpdateAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updateapiview) to simplify it:

```py
class UserOrdersUpdateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User_Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserUser_OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

#### Docs:

> ##### UpdateAPIView
>
> Used for update-only endpoints for a single model instance.
> Provides `put` and `patch` method handlers.
> Extends: GenericAPIView, UpdateModelMixin.

Comment: I get you. But I tried updating the "order" instance values and Im still facing the same problem

Comment: I need more details, do you really need to do all that staff in `save()`method? Or maybe you need to place `Order` instance into serializer instead of `User_Order`?

Comment: I get it now. Your first comment was actually right. I think the problem is I am trying to update the User_Order while it is also acquiring data from the parent model (Order). So the right thing to do is to update the User_Order and the changes will be effected the way I want them.